# How to take message from reaction C# discord

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I have 1 problem I need make bot what if I reaction to message, bot resend this message to other discord channel, but I can't take message from message which I reaction. What I need write  in  ???, I try write message, message.GetOrDownloadAsync, message.DownloadAsync, reaction.Message, but I don't have message, I have something like System.Func`1[System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Discord.IUserMessage]]

```
    private async Task MainAsyns()
    {
        _client.ReactionAdded += HandleReaction;
    }
    private async Task HandleReaction(Cacheable<IUserMessage, ulong> message, Cacheable<IMessageChannel, ulong> channel, SocketReaction reaction)
    {
        var toOtherChanel = _client.GetChannel(_toOtherChanelId) as IMessageChannel;
        var msg = ???;
        if (!_client.GetUser(reaction.UserId).IsBot)
        {
                if (reaction.Emote.Name == "\uD83D\uDC4D")
                {
                    await toOtherChanel.SendMessageAsync($"Message is {msg}");
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ` I have something like System.Func1[System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[Discord.IUserMessage]]` you need to `await` and async methods.... `var msg = message.GetOrDownloadAsync()`